# changing tabbar visibility dynamically in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I have a collection view controller with tab bar controller. When I scrolled down, I want to hide tab bar, but when initialize the controller I need the tab bar seen. But there is an issue with autlayout. So I have to use `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to hide tab bar when initalize the controller to set layouts correctly. Where should I use this code?

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```

I tried to run this code in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear etc. but it doesn't work. Always tab bar seems hide.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement the scrollview delegate for your collection view. By implemented it, you will know if collection is scrolling up or down, then you can hide/show your tabbar